# Count messages from JMS Distributed Queue

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic, java-11

I have several "JMS Distributed Queue's" and I want to check from time to time if there are any queued messages. I have the following code, but the problem with it is that it takes only one of the options and gives me the result, so randomly as an answer I can get 0 as well as 23. Is there a way to call all of them together or iterate over them? As a fact not all Distributed Queue's have the same length.

[image: Distributed Queue Image]

```
package example.jms;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class JMSClient {

@Value("${jms.url}")
private String jmsUrl;

@Value("${jms.username}")
private String jmsUsername;

@Value("${jms.password}")
private String jmsPassword;

@Value("${jms.factory}")
private String dynamicFactory;

@Value("${jms.queue}")
private String dynamicQueue;


public String get() throws Exception {
    try{
        log.debug("[JMS] Sending message to queue");
        InitialContext ctx = getInitialContext(jmsUrl, jmsUsername, jmsPassword);


        QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(dynamicFactory);

        QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        queueConnection.start();

        Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup(dynamicQueue);

        QueueBrowser queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);

        Integer total = Collections.list(queueBrowser.getEnumeration()).size();

        queueConnection.close();

        log.info("Queue size {}", total);
        return "Queue size " + total + ".Name: " + queue.getQueueName();
    } catch(Exception e){
        log.error("[JMS] Exception getting Queue size " + e);
        throw e;
    }
}

private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String jmsUrl, String jmsUsername, String jmsPassword) throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jmsUrl);
    env.put("java.naming.security.principal", jmsUsername);
    env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", jmsPassword);
    return new InitialContext(env);
}
```

}